# Execute trigger function on scroll only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger click event on scroll, when the user scroll down 700px. Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   playVideo();
});

function playVideo() {
    var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (wScroll > 700) {
        $(".video a").trigger("click");
    }
}
```

The problem is that it triggers indefinetely. I tried to ise `one()` with scroll, but it only uses one on scroll while I need it on `trigger("click")`. Please help.

Comment: Just unbind where you trigger

Comment: One solution: Set a class to the `a` after triggering the click and use `:not()` to exclude that in the selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unbind where you trigger:

```
$(window).on("scroll", playVideo);


function playVideo() {
    var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (wScroll > 700) {
        $(".video a").trigger("click");
        $(window).off("scroll", playVideo);
    }
}
```

(please notice that you didn't need to wrap `playVideo` in another function)

Answer (score -1):

```
playVideoBoolean = true;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if (playVideoBoolean == true){
       playVideo();
}
playVideoBoolean = false;
    });

    function playVideo() {
        var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (wScroll > 700) {
            $(".video a").trigger("click");
        }
    }
```

Comment: please remove downvote because that answer was submitted by mistake when i was trying to format my code

Comment: `if (playVideo == true){ playVideo();}`. Guess what that does `true()`

Comment: No it doesn't. If `playVideo==true`, it's not a function so you can't do `playVideo()`.

Comment: playVideo is a boolean variable which is initially set to true and after playing video once it will be false

Comment: i hope it make sense to you